# Javascript: how to create an array with a variable gap between its values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array with a variable gap between its values.

Eg.: supposing my gap equals 15, then my array will be [0, 15, 30, 45, 60].

This is what I have tried to do, but I couldn't make this work.

```
var min_array = 0;
var max_array = 60;
var gap = 15;

var arr = [];

while(min_array < max_array +1){
  arr.push(min_array+gap);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, just as a heads up, the JS for loop can also do this pretty easily.
See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for the documentation.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i+=15) {
    // Parameters: the first argument is your min_array, the next is your max_array, and the final is your gap.
    arr.push(i);
}
```

Comment: almost, just change `i` to start at `0`

Comment: I upvoted everyone's answers, as all of them worked. But I marked yours as accepted because you were beyond the answer, simplifying it and attaching the documentation. Thank you, @Saber Nomen.

Answer (score 3):

You have to count up `min_array` also with `gap`. Otherwise it will end in an infinity loop.

```
while(min_array < max_array){
  arr.push(min_array+gap);
  min_array += gap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code to be like the code below , the problem with your code is that its runs for ever so you need to increase the **min_array** value every time you run the loop .

```js
var min_array = 0;
var max_array = 60;
var gap = 15;

var arr = [];

while(min_array < max_array) {
  min_array = min_array+gap
  arr.push( min_array);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are almost correct, but to include `0` do the following:

```
var min_array = 0;
var max_array = 60;
var gap = 15;

var arr = [];

while(min_array <= max_array){
  arr.push(min_array);
  min_array += gap;
}

console.log(arr);  // [0, 15, 30, 45, 60]
```